# Run AppleScript in the background after switching user

Tags: python, macos, selenium, applescript, macos-catalina

I am currently running a python script that uses the AppleScript, I wish for this to run in the background.

To break it down - it (applescript) selects a file (cmd+shift+g > return > return) and uploads it to chrome (selenium, python). It works fine. However, the issue is that I want this to run in the background.

I was planning on running it on one user profile and leaving the other one free - for personal use. So I can just switch users whenever I like and let the script run in the background (other profile).

When I do so, the AppleScript doesn't work on the profile that runs the script , i.e, it never goes through the process (of cmd+shift+g > return > return) along with the rest of the program.

Since this issue does not revolve around syntax/the code of my program, I haven't included my code - I just want to know how to let my mac execute those commands on the other profile, where I run the applescript.

Comment: You can't as it requires an active GUI session, not running it in the background.

Comment: Is there any other way that I can choose a file where I can run it in the background?